# What is the objective function of the magic square?

Tags: magic-square

If I wanted to describe it as a minimum problem, where I want to identify the minimum value of the constant for a certain matrix order, how should I do it?

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are asking. Nor is it clear why you would want to something complicated when the [magic constant is so easy to calculate directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Magic_constant).

Answer (score 1):

Before we find a function to minimize, we should first find some equalities that determine whether a grid $(a_{ij})$ is a magic square. First off, a magic square has the restriction that the entries $a_{ij}$ are some permutation of $1$ to $n^2$.

Here's a trick to ensure that: We just need to ensure that the polynomial $(X-a_{11}) \cdot (X-a_{12}) \cdots (X-a_{nn})$ is the same as the polynomial $(X-1)\cdot (X-2) \cdots (X-n^2)$. If two polynomials are equal, all their coefficients are equal, so just expand the polynomial in X to get coefficient-wise equalities in $a_{11} \ldots a_{nn}$.

Here's an example for $n = 2$ (I know there aren't any $n=2$ magic squares, but for demonstration purposes): Let's say the magic square is $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. Then the polynomial identity is

$(X-a)(X-b)(X-c)(X-d) = (X-1)(X-2)(X-3)(X-4)$. Expanding both sides yields

$$X^4+(-a-b-c-d)X^3+(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)X^2\\+(-abc-abd-acd-bcd)X+abcd = X^4-10X^3+35X^2-50X+24$$.

Comparing coefficients, we get the following four equations:
$$a+b+c+d=10$$
$$ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=35$$
$$abc+abd+acd+bcd=50$$
$$abcd=24$$

The left sides of these equalities are known as elementary symmetric polynomials.

So far, so good. Now we still need to ensure that the square is *magic*, i.e. that the rows, columns and diagonals are equal. That's more simple, we can just write down a set of equalities for that.

In the case of the magic square $\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}$, the equations are just
$$a+b+c=d+e+f=g+h+i=a+d+g=b+e+h+c+f+i=a+e+i=c+e+g$$

Simple. Now that we have found a way to describe magic squares as a system of equations, we can make it an optimization problem by the following procedure:

For each equality $x = y$ , consider the quadratic difference $(x-y)^2$. The equalities are all true if and only if the sum of the quadratic differences is minimal (i.e. zero). Let's try to construct a minimization problem for $n = 2$ (again, I know there are no $n=2$ magic squares):

Our equalities are
$$a+b+c+d=10$$
$$ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=35$$
$$abc+abd+acd+bcd=50$$
$$abcd=24$$
$$a+b=c+d$$
$$a+b=a+c$$
$$a+b=b+d$$
$$a+b=a+d$$
$$a+b=b+c$$

Together, the term we need to minimize is as follows:

$$(a+b+c+d-10)^2+(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-35)^2+(abc+abd+acd+bcd-50)^2+(abcd-24)^2+(a+b-c-d)^2+(a+b-a-c)^2+(a+b-b-d)^2+(a+b-a-d)^2+(a+b-b-c)^2$$

You might complain that the elementary symmetric polynomials start having a large amount of terms quickly, and you'd be right. Instead of the elementary symmetric polynomials, an equivalent set of equalities is the following power sums (which I won't prove though):

$$a_{11}^1 + a_{12}^1 + \ldots + a_{nn}^1 = 1^1+\ldots+(n^2)^1$$
$$a_{11}^2 + a_{12}^2 + \ldots + a_{nn}^2 = 1^2+\ldots+(n^2)^2$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{11}^{n^2} + a_{12}^{n^2} + \ldots + a_{nn}^{n^2} = 1^{n^2}+\ldots+(n^2)^{n^2}$$

This should make the final term much more easy to write down.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is an $n$ X $n$ square; so clearly it has $n^2$ numbers: from $1$ to $n^2$. Also, let $K$ be the magic constant.

Since this is a magic square, the sum of each row, column and diagonal are equal. For our purpose, let's consider the row-sums only. Since there are $n$ rows which contain all the numbers from $1$ to $n^2$ exactly once, the sum of $n$ rows will equal the sum of numbers from $1$ to $n^2$. This will also equal to the magic constant $K$ times $n$. In other words:

$ 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n^2 = nK $

so,  $\frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2} = nK$

so,  K = $\frac{n(n^2+1)}{2}$

This holds true for all $ n \neq 2 $

Comment: Check out my 3x3 magic square: $\begin{pmatrix}5&5&5\\5&5&5\\5&5&5\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You also need to maximise the size of the set of all values used in the magic square